# SqlException : smalldatetime and time types are incompatible with add operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database on SQL Server 2012 (with 2008 compatibility level), and my code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @BeginTime time
...
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, BeginDate + ' ' + @BeginTime)
FROM MyTable ...
```

`BeginDate` is defined as `smalldatetime`.

This code works well, until I switch the database to 2012 compatibility level, in which case this error shows up:

> SqlException : smalldatetime and time types are incompatible with add operator...

Should I convert my 2 operands to `varchar` before proceeding? Worried about the performance ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server

Comment: What if the small datetime component has a time part? If `BeginDate` is `20151201 23:00:00` and you add `07:00` to it?

Comment: There no time in the field `BeginDate` (data looks like `2011-05-11 00:00:00`), and with same data everything works well when compatibity set to 2008 (100) :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
DECLARE @BeginTime time;
SET @BeginTime = '12:20:00.467'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, BeginDate + CONVERT(SmallDateTime, @BeginTime))
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Conversion from `TIME` / `TIME(7)` to `SMALLDATETIME` will result in a loss of precision.

Comment: Thank you @M.Ali ! Adding convertion from `Time` to `Smalldatetime`, my query works for compatibility 2008 and 2012 !.. May be an implicit conversion was previously made, and now we have to specify it explicitly

Comment: @BogdanSahlean you're right ! converting to `SMALLDATETIME` we will lose seconds and milliseconds... to avoid this, we should convert instead from `TIME` to `DATETIME` ...